# Windows 2008r2 server recovery, blue screen reboot loop

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2

I don't have a system image to recover from or a backup on this server.  It wasn't an important server to start out so it never was added into our backup process.  A couple of nights ago, we lost power and the switch between the iscsi san and the hyper-v hosts.  This ended up corrupting / deleting the crypt32.dll, mshtml.tlb, and ntoskrnl.exe files (they were 0 bytes).

I've got the system to mostly boot then it crashes with a blue screen I can't get the message because it immediately restarts.  According to the registry, it's not supposed to do that; but it is.

I attached the windows 2008r2 setup ISO to the host and booted into the system recovery tool  Unfortunately, I don't have a system image to recover from either.

I was able to load the command program from within the system recovery command prompt.  In the command prompt I ran the system file checker and in the CBS.LOG I found the three files listed above as listed as corrupted and "source file in store is also corrupted".

When I do a dir /s for the files I see many copies in the winsxs subfolders.  in the CBS.LOG on the corrupted files I see that the signature on the files are not the same but I don't see anyway to see that in the command prompt (I can't get a powershell either in system recovery).  It may be possible to find those files on the drive.  However, I'm not sure if it's as simple as copying them into their appropriate place (c:\windows\system32).

If I can recover that way then it would be great.

However...

At this point, I would be happy enough to do an in-place upgrade.  When I select the option to install then upgrade after booting to the disk I get the error "The computer started using the windows installation disc. Remove the installation disc and restart your computer so that the windows starts normally. Then, insert the installation disc and restart the upgrade.  (Do not select "custom (advanced)" to perform ad upgrade. "Custom (advanced)" installs a new copy of windows and deletes your program and settings".

I tested that out with a snapshot and it did delete the previous copy of windows even if I selected to leave the partition intact.

So for me, that's a paradox.  I can't boot windows to start the upgrade recovery but I can't also start that by booting the ISO.

Anyone have an idea on what I can do?

Comment: Use F8 during the boot process to get a boot menu that disables auto-reboot.  Then determine what is causing the blue screen. Consider just a clean install (what did the server do in the first place?  Rather than troubleshooting or even a repair, why not just reload... maybe less of a waste of time.  Then consider taking PERIODIC backups if you don't think it's worth nightly backups.

Comment: I read that a few times as well.. However, the boot menu appears but there is no option to do anything other than the tree safe modes, last known config, and regular  boot.  There's no option for changing parameters like auto reboot or logging. 

The server was just a test server that ended up running some licensing software "temporarily" which wasn't so temporary; it turned out to be much longer.  I was able to copy the VM and mount that partition to a new server image, but it's going to take a while to get everything back...